# PHP - trouble receiving POST json

Tags: php, httprequest

I am writing some simple PHP to receive a POST from another system with a JSON payload. That request is Content-Type: application/json.

I'm simply attempting to dump the json into a txt file as a starting point, but that isn't happening. Here's the PHP file, any suggestions/corrections would be much appreciated!

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");
    session_start();

    $raw_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $cooked_json = json_decode($raw_json);


    $myfile = fopen('/home/wgordon/log.txt','a');
    $fp = fwrite($myfile, $cooked_json);
    fclose($myfile);
```

?>

Comment: the POST request? It may use Ajax, I don't have control over that portion, but if that's something I can see in the request let me know and I'll have a look

Comment: If so, the problem might be that you're not using post. Have you tried dumping the output of post?

Comment: `$raw_json` would be a string not an array

Comment: thanks digitalis, do you mean dumping $_POST to a file in my php?

Comment: I took out this line: $raw_json = $raw_json["data_json"]; which I meant to remove

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure about that anymore, you just read the content of a file, correct? If so, try var_dump($raw_json); just below the file_get_contents();

Comment: just write `$raw_json` to the file.

Comment: so it was my understanding that php://input is an input stream of the raw data in the request body

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it, the initial value of $raw_json would be a string. When you try to access it as an array, you're only going to get a smaller string back. When you pass that to json_decode, it's probably going to return null.

You need to inspect that first value of $raw_json. If it is coming in as a query string of name/value pairs, you'll need to decode it (using split() or something similar) before you can treat it like an array

Comment: Agreed, that seems to be the problem. However, I'm not sure about that url in file_get_contents either. Or is that a placeholder?

Comment: It's an IO stream. Often used for getting data from PUT requests, since they don't come through $_REQUEST

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know that. My apologies.

Comment: It seems no data makes it into $raw_data tho. I tried Musa's suggestion of dumping $raw_data to the file before decoding, and it's still empty. Trying this now with a manual POST. I get a 200 response.

Comment: How are you simulating a POST request to it?

Comment: Actually it looks like the manual POST is working. Using an add-on in Chrome called Simple REST Client, recommend it if you don't have a tool like that.

Comment: $_POST is the way to go for a post request. If you start accepting PUT or DELETE requests, you'll need to use php://input to get the request body data in those cases

Comment: Ok cool, it looks like it's working now. I'll need to read up more on json_decode. Thanks for the help everyone